# Subview goes beneath border Layer - Swift - Programmatically

Tags: swift, uicollectionviewcell, subview, addsubview

I'm setting border of UICollectionViewCell in this way:

```
theView.layer.borderWidth = 5
theView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
```

The problem is that I'm adding a subview over this collectionviewcell and it goes beneath the border like this:

[image]

I actually want to bring the subview over the CollectionViewCell

Code to add subview to cell:

```
plusImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    addSubview(plusImageView)
    plusImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    plusImageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor).isActive = true
```

Comment: Show your code for adding the subview that goes down.

Comment: I added the code I use to add the subview programmatically

Comment: Please put this `addSubview(plusImageView)` after the adding collectionView. Or share an example project with the error.

Answer (score -1):

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622541-bringsubviewtofront

Use parentView.bringSubviewToFront(subview) after adding subview to parent.

Comment: I added the code you suggested but it doesn't work anyway